# Basic definite integral problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What will be the value of $$\int_{0}^{25} e^{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}dx$$? (where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer function)

Edit: I do know that $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ will equate to {x} where { } is the fractional part.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Perhaps on how to reduce this to a simpler computation?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Do you recognize what the function in the exponent looks like, and how it's periodic?

Comment: The function {x} has no fundamental period right?

Comment: @Zlatan:  It does have a fundamental period.  $\{x\} = \{x+1\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you wanted to say $\lfloor x\rfloor$  is the floor function (or the integer part if you like). Noticing that $x-\lfloor x\rfloor=\{x\}$ is a 1-periodic function you get

$$
\int_0^{25}e^{x-\lfloor x\rfloor}dx=\int_0^{25}e^{\{x\}}dx=25\int_0^1e^{\{x\}}dx.
$$
Now, as $\{x\}=x$ for $0\leq x<1$, this equals $25\int_0^1e^xdx=25(e-1).$

Comment: @John could you explain how did you get $\{x\}=x$ for $0\leq x\leq1$ why would the equality exist at x=1? At x=1 shouldn't {x} be 0?

Comment: For $0\leq x<1$, $x$ is "a fractional number" (meaning that it's integral part is 0) so $\{x\}=x$. Youre right about $x=1$, i've already fixed it. Nevertheless it doesn't affect the rest of the proof since single points dont affect integral values (in this Riemann integral)

Comment: Alright thanks for the help! And could you please upvote this question. It really doesn't deserve a -1 vote

Comment: I've tried to edit the question to write $\{x\}$ instead of {}, and to change 'greatest integer function' for 'integer part function' but it wouldnt let me. Still, fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

$e^{x- [x]}= \frac{e^x}{e^{[x]}}$

Now divide the integral into 25 "sub-integrals": 
on x= 0 to 1 this is $\frac{e^x}{e^0}= e^x$.  For x= 1 to 2 this is $\frac{e^x}{e^1}= e^{x- 1}$ .  For x= 2 to 3 this is $\frac{e^x}{e^2}= e^{x- 2}$, etc.

Comment: And what final answer do you hope to get then? Also for the limit 0 to 1 shouldn't put up the values for the exponent (x) of the exponential function?